# How to Print the information using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to print some information using selenium and python but it is printing just one information not all containing the CSS paths this is the while loop how it would be..

```
pageIndex = 1
while True:  # Keep looping through all pages
    # Navigate to the search page
    browser.get("https://www.houz.com/page_num="+ str(pageIndex))
    time.sleep(6)

    links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > h3 > a')
    for link in links:
        urls = link.text


    jobs = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.description')
    for title in jobs:
        jobtitles = title.text


    with open("1Exportdata.csv", "a") as csvFile:
        csvFile.write(url + "," + jobtitle + "\n")

    pageIndex += 1
    if pageIndex == 5010:
        browser.close()
```

Comment: what is the point of just running `for` loops to assign new value to `urls` and `jobtitles`?

Comment: just updated the full loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using:

```
for title in jobs:
    jobtitles = title.text
```

In the first loop, `jobtitles` is the first `title.text`, but then, in the second loop, it become the second `title.text`. Finally it'll become the last `title.text`.

For example:

```
>>> for i in [1, 2, 3]:
...     num = i
>>> print(num)
3
>>>
```

So you need write the `with open("1Exportdata.csv", "a") as csvFile:` inside the `for` loop. Because you have two lists, I'd suggest you use `zip` class zip them:

```
pageIndex = 1
while True:  # Keep looping through all pages
    # Navigate to the search page
    browser.get("https://www.houz.com/page_num="+ str(pageIndex))
    time.sleep(6)

    links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > h3 > a')
    jobs = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.description')

    for link, title in zip(links, jobs):
        url = link.text
        jobtitle = title.text


        with open("1Exportdata.csv", "a") as csvFile:
            csvFile.write(url + "," + jobtitle + "\n")

    pageIndex += 1
    if pageIndex == 5010:
        browser.close()
```

---

Also I think that use `while` loop is useless, try use a `for` loop instead:

```
for pageIndex in range(1, 5011):
    # Navigate to the search page
    browser.get("https://www.houz.com/page_num="+ str(pageIndex))
    time.sleep(6)

    links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > h3 > a')
    jobs = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.description')

    for link, title in zip(links, jobs):
        url = link.text
        jobtitle = title.text


        with open("1Exportdata.csv", "a") as csvFile:
            csvFile.write(url + "," + jobtitle + "\n")
```

Comment: Error

>>> 
  File "C:\Users\Win\Downloads\Runprog\Project cusom taio\Profiles\1.py", line 51, in scraper
    csvFile.write(url + "," + jobtitle + "\n")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2601' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Sarfraz: Hmm...just a typo...what about now?

Comment: I already both changed to singulars already 

 File "C:\Users\Win\Downloads\Runprog\Project cusom taio\Profiles\1.py", line 51, in scraper 
    csvFile.write(url + "," + jobtitle + "\n")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2601' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>
here is the error

Comment: @Sarfraz: I think this problem is about the page source encoding, and then this would be another question. I'd suggest you ask another question about it...but search and try to solve it before you ask it.

Comment: yes I've seen that there is a problem in the source just a tiny issue please let me know if there are two css paths like div > div.description and div > div.description.hover some where used first one and some where second but not identified how I can fix it..